# Billdesk payment gateway integration for Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway

Have done some exploration on available payment gateway APIs for Android and came across 3 whose names cropped up quite a lot:

1) PayPal

2) Stripe

3) Braintree

But my requirement is Billdesk Payment Gateway integration in an Android app. After doing quite a lot of googling and reading blogs, I still have no evidence of Billdesk being used in mobile apps. In fact, even for desktops could find only a couple of links describing how Billdesk payment gateway can be integrated with desktop apps.

So my questions are, can Billdesk payment gateway be integrated with Android apps? If so, can anyone please provide the appropriate info, links?

And if so does Billdesk have a mobile optimized payment gateway or Android compatible API? And is the web services same in that case(Payment request format and response format)?

Sorry for so many questions, but am unable to find a definitive answer so far.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? if so can you please help me with this Billdesk Payment integration

Answer (score 2):

The solution i have used so far is through a web view in android and similar web window components for desktop applications in java swing and vb.net. Actually we just call the web part on the device or desktop application which works same as the web api.